# Rails3: Take control over generated JSON (to_json with datamapper ORM)

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

From my Rails 3 app i want a JSON like this:
    {count:10,
     pictures:[
                {id:1},
     ... ] }
I tried

```
render( :json => { :count => 10, :pictures => @pictures.to_json(:only=>:id) } )
```

but in this case, my pictures get escaped

```
..."pictures":"[{\"id\":2653299}, ....
```

In my old merb app I had the following simple line in my controller:

```
    display( { :count=>@count, :pictures => @pictures } )
```

Because I am using `datamapper` as my ORM and `dm-serializer` I am not sure where to influence the generated json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
render( :json => {:count => 10, :pictures => @pictures })
```

without calling :to_json explicitly on @pictures (the same as it was in your merb app).

However, this will bomb in dm-1.0 without this commit: http://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer/commit/64464a03b6d8485fbced0a5d7150be90b6dcaf2a

I imagine it will be released soon, but in the meantime it's simple to patch.

**edit**

I overlooked the fact that you want to use :only => [:id] on your collection. It looks like :as_json has not been implemented on Collections for whatever reason. You can get around this in several ways. Your example might look like this:

```
render( :json => {:count => 10, :pictures => @pictures.map {|p| p.as_json(:only => [:id])}} )
```

That will turn your Picture collection into a hash of IDs. render will then do its thang properly and you should get your desired results. (hopefully)

Comment: I see. So datamapper is responsible to do the serialization, not some fancy ActiveModel-Module. I'll give it a try at the weekend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "raw" function.  Rails 3 escapes output in the view by default.  Try something like this:

```
raw render( :json => { :count => 10, :pictures => @pictures.to_json(:only=>:id) } )
```

or it may be possible to escape it inside the render function (although, I have never tried this):

```
render( :json => { :count => 10, :pictures => raw(@pictures.to_json(:only=>:id)) } )
```

Comment: Even after some include ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper this does not work, the output will still be escaped.