# Multiple queries on single object in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

When I try to run the following code, DataMapper calls for 3 queries in just these two lines. Can anyone explain why it would do this?

```
 @u = User.first(:uid => 1, :fields => [:uid, :name])
 json @u
```

This calls the following queries:

```
 SELECT "uid", "name" FROM "users" WHERE "uid" = 1 ORDER BY "uid" LIMIT 1
 SELECT "uid", "email"  FROM "users" WHERE "uid" = 1 ORDER BY "uid"
 SELECT "uid", "accesstoken" FROM "users" WHERE "uid" = 1 ORDER BY "uid"
```

It is worth noting that datamapper has a validation on `name` for being `=> unique`

Also, the accesstoken is lazily loaded so it should only be queried when asked for specifically, which must be happening when serializing it to a json object.

EDIT: 
I have added my model class for clarification. I just want one query made for the uid and name without having to extract them individually from the object. Maybe this is the only way?

```
 property :uid,    Serial
 property :name,   String
 property :email,  String
 property :accesstoken, Text
```

ANSWER:
Use the dm-serializer gem that has this support built-in
https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is invoked by your `User.first...` call. Notice the fields it's selecting are what you requested - `uid` and `name`

The second and third queries are getting run in the json serialization, as it's lazy loading each property you didn't already load.

So you either need to do a custom serialization to only output `uid` and `name` for your users, or you should just remove the field selection from your initial query so it all gets loaded at once.

**Update:**
To do a custom serialization with datamapper, you can use the dm-serializer gem https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer and call `@u.to_json(only: [:uid, :name])`

Alternatively in this simple case you could just build the serialized object you want yourself, for which there are many examples: [Rails3: Take controll over generated JSON (to_json with datamapper ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742283/rails3-take-controll-over-generated-json-to-json-with-datamapper-orm)

Comment: Is there a way to serialize only the returned hash from the `User.first` that I run? I only want those two fields returned and when I put the hash, it does only contain those fields. Why does the serialization trigger the extra parameters being searched for?

Comment: After further reading, the dm-serializer gem is able to serialize the current DM object without sending another query! Thanks for the explanation!